# Google sign in with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api

I need a 'sign in with google' button in one of my partials, so I followed google's documentation to integrate the [web sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).
My problem is, I can't get the button to work from a view, only from index(since the meta tags are there). Since I'm using states, I don't want to put code. Basically the following meta tags have to be rendered at the same time as the button:

```
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
```

In my template:

```
        <!--will not work since we're not in index file -->
        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
        <script>
            function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
                // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
            };
        </script>
```

Des anyone has this problem and knows a workound. Thx

Comment: Why not use a plugin? Satellizer.js or hello.js. You can use multiple oauth provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually init auth2 (g-signin2 will use it automatically). Then render the button referencing element id.

Fully working example (just replace YOUR_CLIENT_ID):

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
       alert('onSignIn!');
    }

    function onLoad() {
      gapi.load('auth2,signin2', function() {
        gapi.auth2.init({
          'client_id': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
        });
        gapi.signin2.render('google_signin_button', {
            'onsuccess': 'onSignIn',
            'theme': 'dark'
        });
      });
    }
  </script>

  <div id="google_signin_button"></div>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoad" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```